# sigsegv using vector stl

Tags: c++

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<algorithm>
#include<string.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
  vector<int> a, b,c,d;
  vector<long> Left, Right;
  freopen("input", "r",stdin);
  int n;
  scanf("%d",&n);
  for(int i=0;i<n;i++) {
    long a1, b1, c1, d1;
    scanf("%ld %ld %ld %ld",&a1,&b1,&c1,&d1);
    a.push_back(a1);
    b.push_back(b1);
    c.push_back(c1);
    d.push_back(d1);
  }
  int len=0;
  for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
    {
      long x,y;
      x=(a[i]+b[j]);
      y=(c[i]+d[j]);
      Left.push_back(x);
      Right.push_back(-y);
      len++;
    }
  sort(Left.begin(), Left.end());
  int count=0;
  for(int i=0;i<len;i++)
  {
    long val=Right[i];
    if(binary_search(Left.begin(), Left.end(), val))
      count++;
  }
  printf("%d\n",count);
  return 0;
}
```

Once again I am getting sigsegv for the program. Whenever I use vector I get similar error on spoj but it is working fine on my gcc.

Comment: With what input? Have you tried running it under `valgrind`?

Comment: i don't know the input spoj reported it sigsegv error...

Comment: Well there are clearly inputs that will cause this code to fault. For example, if you exceed `MAX`. Unless you have inputs that are supposed to work that actually don't, it's "working as designed".

Comment: Please link to the problem in spoj

Comment: You shouldnt mess C with C++ in this way, also you should dig into code styles. In example google style. It is really hard to read it.

Comment: @izomorphius please see the link http://www.spoj.pl/problems/SUMFOUR/

Answer (score 1):

You should remove the freopen, because otherwise you will never read their input. When I did remove it my code recieved wrong answer and there is a reason for that. Please read the following tips:

- the complexity of your algorithm is 4000 * 4000 * log(4000^2) which is too slow. Try to think of a better(faster solution). In fact you are thinking in the correct direction, just try to avoid the logarithm.
- long and int is the same on most contemporary judge machines. I never use long in competetive programming. When you need type bigger then int use "long long"
- it can be the case that a given sum of values a + b can be achieved using more then one pair of values from A and B respectively.

Comment: please i am not clear about how you are calculating extra log(4000^2)..please comment..

Comment: i am not clear about how you are calculating extra log(4000^2)..please comment

Comment: The log(4000^2) come from the call `if(binary_search(Left.begin(), Left.end(), val))` You can optimize your algorithm to traverse left and right once instead of doing binary search for each element of right.